Can I use `using` in class constructor overload?
I'd like to call another of my class's constructor overloads from one of my class's other constructors.
The other overload is to be provided with a new object that's IDisposable:
public class Test
{
    public Test(string path) : this(using new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {   }

    public Test(Stream stream) { }
}

The above code is invalid.
How would I do that right?

What are you trying to achieve?

I'd like to call another of my class's constructors from another of my class's constructors while providing it with a new, disposable object.

No makes no sense, as the stream will be disposed immediately, rather than when Test is disposed (which you should add IDisposable to)

This sounds like an X/Y problem, because what you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please see [ask].

This is a formal, language related question. In both cases, the caller is supposed to control the stream. It's closed by the caller, immediately.

The first constructor is the caller. I'm not sure why this is unclear here.

You can't do this directly. Instead, have both constructors call a private Initialize method that takes a Stream, with the string-argument constructor wrapping the Initialize call within a using statement.

@AxD "This is a formal, language related question" - No, this really isn't...

Avoid doing anything CPU-intensive, throwing exceptions, allocating resources, I/O, making database or network connections or, really, anything other than initializing member fields, in your constructors. Constructors get called in places, like the debugger, remote procedures, external threads, serialization, p/Invoke, and other things you won't know about. Trying to do anything heavyweight in constructors leads to incomprehensible behavior like nulls calling methods, your app running differently in the debugger and in production, and other things. The only way to win is by not playing.

What would using mean here? When do you want the stream to be disposed? This is well-defined for regular usings. When would a using in a constructor call dispose its resources?

@DourHighArch Well, throwing exceptions in a constructor is fine, since it's the only way to report errors from them.

Have you ever used StreamReader/StreamWriter?

Manage the lifecycle of the Stream object within the lifecycle of the Test class, rather than within the constructor. Because you're going to manage the Stream in the same lifecycle as the Test class, the Test class should implement IDisposable.
public class Test(Stream stream) : IDisposable
{
    public Test(string path) : this(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stream.Dispose();
    }

    // if you want to expose the stream outside the class, this is an option
    public Stream Stream { get { return stream; } }
}

The second constructor, which take the path, doesn't have a using. It creates a new Stream which is then disposed when the containing class is disposed, which is the same behavior as if you called the primary constructor directly passing in a Stream.

public class Test(Stream stream) means you're using the new C# primary-constructors, which are (unfortunately) horribly compromised because they introduce mutability in places where people assume things are immutable.

I would not recommend wholesale Disposing a stream that could be given to this class by an external component. Either the constructor should take an argument indicating whether this class owns the stream, or some kind of flag should be set by the constructor that creates the FileStream, so Dispose only disposes the stream in that case.

You can achieve this functionality in a shorter and cleaner way by using a helper method and ensuring proper disposal through a simple wrapper or directly in the constructor. Here's a more concise version
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;

    public Test(string path) : this(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }

    public Test(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _stream?.Dispose();
    }
}

In this version, the Test class implements IDisposable to ensure the stream is disposed of when the Test object is no longer needed. The constructor that takes a string simply creates a FileStream and passes it to the other constructor. The Dispose method takes care of disposing of the stream.

See my comment on the other answer: it's usually not a good idea to dispose a stream that another class passes into this class's constructor.
